# Add a dropdown arrow to jquery autocomplete text field

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have a form with 2 fields - vendor and pav. The vendor currently is an autocomplete textfield that, once a vendor is chosen it populates the pav field with the corresponding value. What I would like to do is add a drop down arrow and or scroll bar on the text field so that once the user begins typing they can scroll up and down. What I would ***really*** like to do is change the text field to a autocomplete comobox but the tutorials I found were a bit advanced for my limited knowledge in jquery.

Another option I did find was to show the entire list once a user focuses on a field using

```
.bind('focus', function(){ $(this).autocomplete("search"); } );
```

but am unclear as to where to put this in my code.

Following is my jquery code for the autocomplete:

```
    `Drupal.behaviors.mywebform = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
                $('#edit-submitted-vendor-exhibitor-info-pav').val("");
```

```
            $("#edit-submitted-vendor-exhibitor-info-vendor").autocomplete({
                source: "/shipONE/sites/vendorarray.php",
                minLength: 1,

                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $('#edit-submitted-vendor-exhibitor-info-vendor').val(ui.item.vendor);
                    $('#edit-submitted-vendor-exhibitor-info-pav').val(ui.item.pav);            
                }
            });
   }};`
```

And the code for my php that returns the values from the database:

```
    $return_arr = array();
```

```
if ($conn)
{
    $ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM vendors2 where vendor like :term";
    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
    $result->execute();

    /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['pav'] = $row['pav'];
        $row_array['value'] = $row['vendor'];
        $row_array['pav'] = $row['pav'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
}

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the focus on field working (which also gave me a drop down with scrollbar) by doing the following:

New JS

```
       Drupal.behaviors.mywebform = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
        $('#edit-submitted-vendor-exhibitor-info-pav').val(""); 

        $("#edit-submitted-vendor-exhibitor-info-vendor").autocomplete({
            source: "/shipONE/sites/vendorarray.php",
            minLength: 0,
            scroll: true,
            select: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).autocomplete('disable');
$('#edit-submitted-vendor-exhibitor-info-vendor').val(ui.item.vendor);
$('#edit-submitted-vendor-exhibitor-info-pav').val(ui.item.pav);
}
}}  .blur(function(){
        $(this).autocomplete('enable');
    })
    .focus(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete('search', '');
    });

}};
```

And also added to my css the following to add a scroll bar and limit the options being shown:

```
.ui-autocomplete { 
height: 200px; 
overflow-y: scroll; 
overflow-x: hidden;}
```